# Multiple views in a UIWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a "navigation based application" which also needs to have a view always displayed at the bottom of the screen at all times. I added this new view to a UIWindow after adding the UINavigationController's view:

```
// In my delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window insertSubview:disclaimerController.view aboveSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This works fine except for rotation. The second view I added doesn't rotate correctly. It doesn't change position and it's view controller's rotate methods don't get called.

Obviously, I'm going about this the wrong way. My question is, how can I have a second view on screen that's not part of navigation controller's view? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding a view on top of another by adding as subview rotation will not work (view won't be notified of rotation). What you can do is register the view with the device to be notified of rotation events, then you can programatically handle rotation (it will not do it for you).

Comment: I'm not sure I explained the issue correctly. This was specific to the UIWindow where the first view added to the UIWindow would rotate correctly and any subsequent views would not rotate or resize at all, but stay in a fixed position. My solution has been to only add the NavigationController's view to the window and add any subsequent views to the NavigationController's view.

Comment: O you added two views to the window?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be a solution since I wanted something separate from the Navigation Controller's view.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a view of another view controller as a subview to the active window of the application you must synchronize its `center`, `bounds` and `transform` properties with `window.rootViewController.view`. Also be sure your top view is added **after** correct initialization of the window, and also **after** its root subview has been added to it as a subview.

I suppose this can be done in multiple ways, I've made it work through use of [Key-value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Here the `topViewController` is instance of a `UIViewController` subclass and it represents the view controller of the `UIView` that should be on top of the application window

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addObserver:topViewController forKeyPath:@"transform" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"rootView"];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addObserver:topViewController forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:@"rootView"];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addObserver:topViewController forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:@"rootView"];
    return YES;
}
```

`topViewController`'s `.m` file:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([(__bridge_transfer NSString*)context isEqualToString:@"rootView"])
    {
        if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"transform"])
        {
            self.view.transform = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGAffineTransformValue];
        }
        else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"]) 
        {
            self.view.center = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGPointValue];
        }
        else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"bounds"]) 
        {
            self.view.bounds = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGRectValue];
        }
        else 
        {
            [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Comment: By further examination, this gets messed up whenever a different view is on the bottom of the main UIWindow's subview Array. (This happens when e.g. MoviePlayerViewController is presented) This can still however be managed by subclassing the UIWindow and keeping a reference to the first subview in methods like addSubview,insertsubview:atindex and willRemoveSubview

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960988/202451

It should bring you closer to doing custom things like that :)