# Remove view from screen iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have the schema like that:

```
----- main view    
       |
        ---right bar view
             |
              ----- Navigation Controller view
                     |
                     ------tableView Controller
```

how can i remove the right bar view from the window when i'm on tableViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 [self.view.superview.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

Another approach, much cleaner, would be using notifications: you could send a notification to the object controlling your main view, so that it removes it right bar subview. It would be something like:

In your main view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(removeRightBar:) 
    name:@"RemoveRightBarNotification"
    object:nil];


- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
     <REMOVE SUBVIEW FROM mainView>
}
```

and in your table view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"RemoveRightBarNotification" 
    object:self];
```

In this case notification will provide a very loose connection between the main view and the table view controller.

Comment: If I did not understand correctly your question, maybe some more details are needed... what do you mean by "remove the right bar view"? what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have the main screen and a helper bar on the right i want to remove that helper bar when a button tapped!

Comment: that actually worked needed some customization [self.view.superview.superview.superview.superview removeFromSuperview]; But it's not that pretty

Comment: @Filippos Zampounis: please see my edit for a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use tag to the view you are going to delete and remove the view with the reference of that tag.
like:
Before adding the Right Bar View to the main view (self.view) add a tag

```
rightBarView.tag   =   1;
```

and for deleting the pirticular view write

```
for(UIView *temp in [self.view subviews]) {
    if (temp.tag == 1) {
        [temp removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: that's what i tried but didn't work so i had to add something like that before the for loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843411/getting-reference-to-the-top-most-view-window-in-ios-application

Comment: thanks a lot really nice solution but the hard time was to find the view on the screen self.view didn't help a lot!