# Way to record and then play all UIEvents of UIApplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, uievent

Is there any way to record and then play all UIEvents of UIApplication?
Main idea is to record testing scenario and then play it and compare results.

I have managed to get all app events after subclassing UIApplication, but still I cant play them with any delay.

```
@interface MyApplication : UIApplication
@end

@implementation MyApplication

(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super performSelector:@selector(sendEvent:) withObject:event afterDelay:0.0];  // nothing happens
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found solution
https://github.com/square/KIF
contains UIView-KIFAdditions
with method that provides opportunity to send a touch event

also this links may be usefull
[How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746452/how-to-send-a-touch-event-to-iphone-os)
[Getting reference to the top-most view/window in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843411/getting-reference-to-the-top-most-view-window-in-ios-application)

Answer (score 2):

You can make test scenario using:

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)

[KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF)

or something else test frameworks.

Comment: I have read about cucumber and still i don't want to write tests in format [scenario addStep:...] or something like that, it would take to much time as to me.