# How to add an UIView to the front most view of the whole iOS in the tweak application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, mbprogresshud, tweak

My app is a tweak app running in `SpringBoard`, in which I want to use `MBProgressHUD`, but it need to specify a view to add to, so how can I get the font most view of the whole `iOS`?

I should do like that:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:fronMostView animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.labelText = [Localization localize:@"Finished!"];
[hud hide:YES afterDelay:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to add this view is `AppDelegate`. Add view in to appDelegate window will show to top front for whole application. Also it remains on top until you hide or remove this view from appDelegate window.

Create a global object of `MBProgressHUD` in `AppDelegate` class and create show/hide methods.

Call this methods respectively for your convenience use.

For Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  MBProgressHUD   *hud;

- (void) showProgress:(NSString *)message {

    // Create a loading view
    if (!self.hud) {
        _hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:fronMostView animated:YES];
        self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;

        // Add Progress to window.
       [self.window addSubview:self.hud];
    }

    self.hud.hidden = NO;
    self.hud.labelText = [Localization localize:message];
}


- (void) hideLoadingMessage {
    self.hud.labelText = [Localization localize:@"Finished!"];
    [self.hud hide:YES afterDelay:1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my tweak app is running at `SpringBoard`, where I can't find the `AppDelegate `.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

or

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
```

Then

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
```

[Here is a topic about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843411/getting-reference-to-the-top-most-view-window-in-ios-application), maybe it'll be useful.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me, because my tweak app is running inside `SpringBoard`.