# How to differentiate top windows in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiwindow

Following the strategy from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843411/getting-reference-to-the-top-most-view-window-in-ios-application), in iOS 7 I could find the top window in my app like so:

```
UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
    return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
}] lastObject];
```

However, since iOS8 there may be one or more `UITextEffectsWindow`s which may be the `lastObject` in the above strategy. No good.

Initially I could run a predicate filter on the array of windows and test which windows are `UIWindow`s like so:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
    return [obj isMemberOfClass:[UIWindow class]];
}];
```

However, the top `UIWindow` may *not* be `UIWindow`, but some subclass like [NRWindow](https://github.com/natanrolnik/NRTouchPoints). Here is an example:

```
[[NRWindow class] isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]; // true
[[UITextEffectsWindow class] isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]; // true
```

**My question is this:** How can I safely differentiate/find the top `UIWindow` subclass so I can do things like

```
[[topWindow rootViewController] presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(Note: Testing for `UITextEffectsWindow` directly is frowned upon, and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` unfortunately isn't reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only want to present from windows that you have created. So you could:

- Write a subclass of UIWindow and use that when creating your windows. Then you can test for windows of that subclass.
- Add an [associated object](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to all windows that are eligible for presenting a modal view. Then you can test for the associated object when searching for a window.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I do not control which windows are created. In debugging one team may add an NRWindow, which the screenshot team may add another window with pretty overlays.