# How to determine if a UIView is obscured or partially off-screen with hit tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview

I'm looking for a way to test if a UIView is (partially) obscured by an UIActionSheet, UIAlertView, HUD, etc., or if it is (partially) off the screen in a sliding panel, UIScrollView, etc.. This needs to be a generic solution because there are too many ways to obscure a view.

What comes to mind is to perform a few **hit tests** at key points where the UIView should be and check how many, if any, hit the given UIView.

**Example:** Imagine there is no hand in the image below. I'd like to perform a programmatic hit test at the point where the finger is. If `View A.2` is not returned, then it is obscured.

[image: touch event]

I've looked into [hit tests with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961492/1938889), but how can I programmatically perform a hit test and see which UIView is hit **without physical touch events**?

*References:*

- [Hit-Testing in iOS](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/)
- [Event handling for iOS - how hitTest:withEvent: and pointInside:withEvent: are related?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961492/1938889)

Answer (score 0):

I found one answer.

First, convert the coordinates of the view you want to perform a hit test on (let's use `UIView *testView`) to those of the screen coordinates.

```
CGPoint screenOrigin = 
     [testView.superview convertPoint:testView.frame.origin 
                               toView:nil];
```

Next, make a couple test hit points (for example, for the upper left and lower right corners of the view). This is an example of one test point.

```
CGPoint hitTestPoint = CGPointMake(30, screenOrigin.y + 30); // upper left
```

Then find the top most window<sup>*</sup> and call `hitTest:withEvent:` on it. The event can be nil.

```
UIView *hitTest = [mainWindow hitTest:hitTestPoint withEvent:nil];
```

Then check if the `hitTest` result is equal to the `testView`:

```
if (testView && [testView isEqual:hitTest] /* && [testView isEqual:hitTest2] */) {
    // The view is not obscured nor off the screen in a sliding panel
}
```

---

*Finding the top most window is still [an open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375915/how-to-differentiate-top-windows-in-ios8), but for most people something like this may work:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject]
```