# What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

It appears that side-swipe menus are becoming a more common interface element as more information gets crammed into each iPhone app.  Facebook has included it in their latest version and [the new Gmail app appears to include it as well](http://www.theverge.com/2011/11/2/2533321/gmail-ios-hands-on).  I was wondering if anybody had thoughts on the most efficient way of developing something like this as it's becoming a more common interface element.   While I have my own thoughts on how to build this, I'm curious to hear what other people think.

[image: Facebook swipe navigation]

Comment: I've noticed, that when sideswipe menu is activated, you can't do anything with swiped-out part of the view. My idea was to render current view in image and display portion of it, when sideswipe is activated

Comment: Whose Facebook profile did you peek in, Nick O'Neill? :-p

Comment: possible duplicate of [SplitView but on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-but-on-iphone)

Comment: Ooh! Ooh! Don't forget to put one on the right side, too!

Comment: @Zoidberg I'm interested to hear more about this. Personally, I like the sidenav! But I am a developer, not a designer. What makes this UX poor?

Comment: @Denis I'd like to point out that Facebook doesn't do that, if you scroll down the page and while the page is still scrolling you tap the button on the bar to pull out the side-bar the page keeps scrolling. However, that is a nice idea :) It might free up some memory!

Comment: iOS 7 too has slide to right feature. Will it cause any problem with this?

Comment: Check the [AMSlideMenu](https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu) library. Its fully customizable, currently has no known bugs!

Comment: Please anyone watch [Designing Intuitive User Experiences](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#211-video) to learn about what issues apple has identified with this so-called "hamburger menus"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recently came across this, didn't actually look at the code or test the control, but looks like it may be a very decent starting point.

[jtrevealsidebar](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtrevealsidebar)

Edit:
The reader should also take a look at the other answers :)

Comment: Doesn't allow the user to slide

Comment: If you looking for swipe functionality. Insert a gesture recognizer to the view then replace the toggle button with the gesture recognizer.

Comment: But what if you want to swipe and be able to toggle?

Comment: This is discontinued so I would move elsewhere.

Answer (score 84):

There is a great library for this by Tom Adriaenssen: [Inferis/ViewDeck](http://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)

It's very easy to use and has a fairly large following.

**EDIT:**

For something a little more lightweight, check out: [mutualmobile/MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

It doesn't have all of the features of ViewDeck but is simpler to modify and extend.

Comment: I recommend everybody use this.

Comment: best solution: flexible and simple to use

Comment: I tried it and found a lot of Bugs in their Example. After some fast clicks the viewcontrollers are misaligned

Comment: @TorstenB I've used it for several apps and it always seems to work fine for me. That being said, if you have a reproducible bug, try filing an issue [here](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/issues). The library is still actively being developed so there is a good chance someone will help you with your issue.

Comment: We've used it for several apps, but it was very difficult to maintain and add new features to it. It also has suffered from trying to implement too much.

We decided to write our own called MMDrawerController. Light-weight, and focused: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: MMDrawerController is very good library .Also it's support universial app. iphone and ipad apps

Comment: ViewDeck is no longer maintained as of November 2014. The issues list is growing constantly. The last real commit was in May 2013. Until they can pick up a maintainer, I recommend new projects use another option.

Answer (score 48):

I created a library for this. It is called [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu).

Among other things it includes support for iphone+ipad, portrait+landscape, menu on the left or right side, UITabBarController, and pan gestures.

Comment: Its a great project .. but Its not supporting for landscape mode.. Can u give us a hint to use it in landscape mode too .. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @SameeraChathuranga. I hope to add landscape support if I get some time. The only part that doesn't have landscape support is the SideMenuViewController... I believe you would have to do something like the 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508630/orientation-in-a-uiview-added-to-a-uiwindow. Feel free to fork and contribute to the repo!

Comment: And I recommend this is the answer for this question .. not the above one .. its too complex.. this is very very easy to handle :) if some one want i can post the code, how to work with oriantation .. :)

Comment: For anyone that's interested, I just added landscape support to the library.

Comment: I realized that your library performance is bad. My app performance decreased since I added your library. Can u realize?

Comment: Yes, my app bad performance wad because of ur library. Now, I used ViewDeck library, performance now is amazing. You should make optimizations to your library. good luck!

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek, can you explain what parts of your app experienced a decrease in performance? I would be happy to make any necessary optimizations.

Comment: I just used ur library. I succeeded with integration, build sidemenu, everything worked. When I started to build my centerView with UITableView, when I scroll table performance is not as it should be. It's not smooth. Just like android scrolling effect, not like an apple's smooth.

Comment: Michael Frederick .....How to use this libary in Tabased Application in xcode 4.2...

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek please open an issue and provide me with your code. If the problem is with the library I will definitely fix it.

Comment: @sai the sample project now includes an example of using MFSideMenu with a UITabBarController

Comment: @ 
Michael Frederick   Ohh..kindly give me that URl

Comment: Can you please add a demo for using it with iPad + Storyboard?

Comment: This is the best library project for having side menus. Awesome work.
But I just have one issue, I need to hide the status bar when the Menus are on and make it visible as I close the menu. Any help for this ?

Comment: @MichaelFrederick Thanks for wonderful MFSideMenu lib, I have two doubts 
1. Is it supporting storyboard ?
2. How to set center, left and right view controllers, If Side Menu need to add in after two - three view controllers in stack ? In my case I have registration screen before moving to Side Menu screen?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29):

Check out MMDrawerController:

[MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

We couldn't find a library that we liked, so we just rolled our own.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is BY FAR the best implementation listed here. People new to this thread: use MMDrawerController.

Comment: Appreciate the kind words!

Comment: I was using ViewDeck from past one year but I recently switched to MMDrawerController and I recommend everybody to use this. One of the best implementation in overall libraries. Thanks Kevin :)

Comment: Checked this MMDrawerController and want to say that it's really the best option for side menu. Appreciated! Big thank you to @Michael Frederick

Comment: Does this support iOS8? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The **key idea** that you have to **set self.navigationController.view's frame or center**. There is **two event** that you have to handle. (1) **barButtonItem press**. (2) **pan gesture** because of swiping.

You can send view controller to the background like this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    CGRect destination = self.navigationController.view.frame;

    if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
        destination.origin.x = 0;
    } else {
        destination.origin.x = 320;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.navigationController.view.frame = destination;
    }];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    static CGPoint originalCenter;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalCenter = recognizer.view.center;

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y);
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        if (recognizer.view.frame.origin.x < 160) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(384, 487.5);
            }];
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(384 + 320, 487.5);
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect and without too much code. You only need to specify the limits where the user can pan so your view

Comment: @Janos sir kindly help me am lacking in this for more days

Comment: I have created the side out menu with the help of your above code, when slideout the back side shows only dark color not the view kindly help me

Comment: Sir it works fine I use this above code only. the only thing is the background view dosn't shows I have upoted it please help me to show the background view

Comment: @János  and where to use this line of code [self.view sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];

Comment: have you checked with `Debug View Hierarchy`?

Comment: no i am new to iOS where to use this line of code [self.view sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];

Comment: @János please help me where to use this line of code [self.view sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];

Comment: I don't think that line is imortant at all, the concept is to set the frame of the container view, and handle the two event, pressing button, and panning

Answer (score 11):

Facebook's implementation places a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the UINavigationBar. Thus allowing to catch swipes where it's needed.

That allows to do things like, recognizing the touch direction in x/z directly as well as the speed they occurred with.

Also such kind of tinkering with UIViews (more than one on screen at a time with evidently different tasks -> thus different controllers) should (I'm tempted to say must) use iOS new ViewController-Containment features. Every implementation without that is simply bad as it tinkers with the view hierarchy in a way not intended by Apple.

On a sidenote: If you're really curious on how it can be done as close to Facebook's way as possible, check out the project I open sourced on Github [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) .

Comment: There is nothing wrong (or HIG non-compliant) with managing UIView-based custom UI.  View controller containment came too late, so plenty of other approaches have been used.  A related article: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: Major developments won't be targeting a minimum version of iOS 5 for a long time, since a large number of users won't upgrade for a very long time.  While many of them are 'hacks' as you say, it can certainly be done correctly.  Staying within frameworks is definitely a safe bet, but sometimes a unique and custom UI requires more.

Answer (score 11):

Even better is *JASidePanels*. Easily implemented and works for both iPhone and iPad.

Github link: [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)

Answer (score 8):

There are tens of different libraries that developers have created to implement the Facebook/Path style navigation for iOS apps. I can list all of them but as you have asked for the best one, here are my two choices that i use to implement the side swipe navigation menu:

1) [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)
Its very easy to implement and use Storyboards also. I haven't had any issues implementing it nor received any errors or anything like that. The link i provided has pretty much all the explanation in order to use it.

2) [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)
This library is easy to use and you can find a tutorial [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/), that shows how to implement it with all the explanation along with images. You can just follow the tutorial and thank me later.

Comment: SWRevealViewController is simplest one , used it no bugs works good

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use [Scringo](http://www.scringo.com) . It gives you a side-menu like in youtube/facebook apps, and also all kind of built-in features in the menu that you can choose to add (e.g chat, invite friends, etc...)

Adding the side-menu is simply by calling [ScringoAgent startSession...] and all configuration can be done on the site.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to here, a very good starting point:
[slide out navigation like facebook and path](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path)

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite popular but it all came down to easy importing and use for me... Here is what I use... [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

I'm surprised people miss it... It really is GREAT!!! and easy to use. The developer even includes a few example projects that allow you to see how to use it in different scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

A excellent guide to how develop your own Slide-Out-Navigation in Swift and Objective-C.

**Objective-C**

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

**Swift**

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Answer (score 2):

Both Gmail and Facebook make heavy use of web views, so it's hard to say what's native code and what's rendered HTML. However, looking at the interface, it looks like they've placed a UITableView with a width narrower than the screen width (320pt) underneath of a UIView that contains the content they want to display. Selecting different tableview rows probably swaps out a subview of the content view.

At least, that's how I'd approach the problem. It's hard to dictate what it should be. Just jump right in and start experimenting!

Comment: hey can any one tell me how to create the facebook type swipe view and the menu panel in android

Answer (score 1):

the view in the right could be inside a subclass of UIScrollView. In this subclass you can override `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to return YES only if the user touched the subview. This way you can place your transparent UIScrollView over any other view and pass through any touch event that takes place outside the subview; and you get scroll stuff for free.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint location=[self convertPoint:point toView:subview];
    return (location.x > 0 && 
            location.x < subview.frame.size.width && 
            location.y > 0 && 
            location.y < subview.frame.size.height);
}
```

or:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return [subview pointInside:
             [self convertPoint:point toView:subview] withEvent:event];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your menu (that you swipe to get to) underneath the main view.  Begin subscribing to touch events in the view.

Implement `touchesMoved:`, and check to see if the first `gesture` is vertical (scroll the main view, if needed), or horizontal (here you'd want to show the menu).  If it's horizontal, begin invoking another method, `- (void)scrollAwayMainView:(NSUInteger)pixels`, whenever `touchesMoved:` gets called, calculating the number of pixels away from the starting point the main view should be, and passing that number into the method.  In that methods implementation, run the following code:

```
[mainView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake:(pixels, 
                                          mainView.origin.y, 
                                          mainView.size.width, 
                                          mainView.size.height];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want I did this repo on github [GSSlideMenu](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/GSSlideMenu)
It allow you to create a Facebook-style menu BUT with a "back" webView (generally all repos that I've found has a tableView as the "back" view).

Answer (score 1):

this is exactly the clone of the facebook sidebar :
[GHSidebarNav library](https://github.com/crino/GHSidebarNav)

very easy to use. instruction are in

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution for this question:

[How to create custom slide menu without third party library.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045208/how-to-create-custom-slide-menu-without-third-party-library/37047366#37047366)

One single class that you only need to subclass and fill in with content.

Here is the class. For more details, see the above link.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IS_SlideMenu_View : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIView* transparentBgView;
    BOOL hidden;
    int lastOrientation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *menuContainerV;

+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (BOOL)isShown;
- (void)hideSlideMenu;
- (void)showSlideMenu;

@end


#import "IS_SlideMenu_View.h"

@implementation IS_SlideMenu_View

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static id _sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        transparentBgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [transparentBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.6]];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:0];
        transparentBgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognized:)];
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognized:)];
        [transparentBgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [transparentBgView addGestureRecognizer:pan];

        [self addSubview:transparentBgView];

        frame.size.width = 280;
        self.menuContainerV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        CALayer *l = self.menuContainerV.layer;
        l.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        l.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 0);
        l.shadowOpacity = 1;
        l.masksToBounds = NO;
        l.shadowRadius = 10;
        self.menuContainerV.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [self addSubview: self.menuContainerV];
        hidden = YES;
    }

    //----- SETUP DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGE NOTIFICATION -----
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:device];

    lastOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    return self;
}

//********** ORIENTATION CHANGED **********
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];    
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        NSLog(@"%ld",orientation);
        if(!hidden && lastOrientation != orientation){
            [self hideSlideMenu];
            hidden = YES;
            lastOrientation = orientation;
        }
    }
}

- (void)showSlideMenu {
    UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height);

    [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-window.frame.size.width, 0)];

    [window addSubview:self];
//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:1];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Show complete!");
        hidden = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)gestureRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [self hideSlideMenu];
    } else if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        static CGFloat startX;
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            startX = [recognizer locationInView:self.window].x;
        } else
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            CGFloat touchLocX = [recognizer locationInView:self.window].x;
            if (touchLocX < startX) {
                [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(touchLocX - startX, 0)];
            }
        } else
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            [self hideSlideMenu];
        }
    }
}

- (void)hideSlideMenu
{
    UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.window.frame.size.width, 0)];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

//        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Hide complete!");
    }];
}

- (BOOL)isShown
{
    return !hidden;
}

@end
```