# iphone facebook side menu using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

The facebook iphone app has a new side menu,
[image: screen]
<sub>(source: [tapscape.com](http://www.tapscape.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/facebook2.jpg))</sub>

Does anyone know how i can implement this feature in my iphone application and using objective c?

Comment: Check [this library](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/zuuirevealcontroller). Helped me! It is finished library doing that really good!

Comment: Very simple and easy to use  https://github.com/shivamchove/facebook_style_left_menus library

Answer (score 49):

It's pretty simple really.  First, you need to make a view controller that sits under the one that's visible.  You can send that view to the back like this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];
```

Then, you put a menu button on the left side of your navigation bar, and write a handler kind of like this:

```
- (void)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    CGRect destination = self.navigationController.view.frame;

    if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
        destination.origin.x = 0;
    } else {
        destination.origin.x += 254.5;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        self.navigationController.view.frame = destination;        

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = !(destination.origin.x > 0);

    }];
}
```

That's the general idea.  You may have to change the code to reflect your view hierarchy, etc.

Comment: @greenisus I'm confused on how you sent the menu to the back? When I do that it just shows a black side menu.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks! does anyone know how to handle orientation changes for this side menu?

Comment: can i do this for a tab bar view controller . basically planning to hide the tab bar in the bottom

Comment: This works when you have 2 UIViewControllers on top of each other and you move the one on top to the side to see the "menu" view under it. I need to have the one on top be a UINavigationController but cannot achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Bot Were you ever able to get the UIViewController underneath to become visible?

Comment: How do you add the childViewController's view as a subview? do you set its frame explicitly?

Comment: @greenisus Whose subview is the childviewcontroller's view and what frame is it given?

Comment: @Piotr see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914070/send-subview-to-back  I also have `appointmentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppointmentViewController"];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appointmentViewController];
    self.navController.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self addShadowToMenu];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.navController.view];
 
    self.sideMenu.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` in my side menu viewDidLoad

Comment: I added a button on side view, but when I am trying to click it, it is not responding to associated action :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see all these questions until tonight.  When I did this, I used UIViewController containment had a UIViewController that had two child UIViewControllers.  The button on the "content" view controller would send a message up to the root container view controller and that would handle the animation.