# How to create a menu like the Facebook App Menu on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I want to have something like this in my app:

[image: Example Image]

A main view that you can slide to the right, and behind it a `UITableView`. If you drag the main view to the right, you should be able to drag it back in, even if you start dragging to the left on top of the `UITableView` (if I pan left or right on top of the `UITableView` the main view should be moved, if I drag up or down on top of the `UITableView` the `UITableView` should scroll). Furthermore, it would be nice if the main view would drop a shadow on to the `UITableView`.

Comment: Could have been created by facebook themselves. I am interested to see if this UI is default in iOS.

Comment: It is not a default UI in iOS at present.

Comment: This question is old but for those that stumbled upon it please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991034/iphone-facebook-side-menu-using-objective-c. It has numerous libraries and even an example for a custom menu.