# menu for my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to make a menu for my iPhone pong app,
When I looked online everything was either on old Xcode, different menu, or not in an empty application than I want. When I made my app I used an empty application, and need to make a menu with a button like play that opens up my game in a different view.
Tell me if you want any of my code for help, and FYI I am a beginner to making apps.
Thanks!!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials in the net, try a little bit more on searching.

Comment: I've tried MF, DG, and some others. Still no luck getting this added to my project correctly. Wish someone would add a real answer (no pies...).

Answer (score 2):

1. [Open Source Pop-Out Pie Style Menu iOS Control With A Nice
   Animation Effect](http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-add-a-rotating-pie-menu-to-your-ios-apps/)
2. [Pie Menus on iOS](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/09/08/pie-menus-on-ios/)
3. [Tutorial: How To Add A
   Rotating Pie Menu To Your iOS Apps](http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-add-a-rotating-pie-menu-to-your-ios-apps/)

And similar questions:

1. [iphone facebook side menu using objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991034/iphone-facebook-side-menu-using-objective-c)
2. [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

Here's a great list of menus, check this site:

1. [iOS Open Source Facebook/Path liked Sidebar Menu implementation](http://bitly.com/bundles/o_27ukkruo5l/1)

There, next time, bother a little more on searching :) 
Hope this helps.

Comment: do you like pie by any chance?