# How to create a sidebar similar to the facebook app for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

How can i create a sidebar similar to the facebook app for iOS (iPhone/iPad)?  That sidebar that appears when you slide your finger horizontally. There is a component for this or is it just a UIView?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're in luck! Somebody just created a complete sample app showing how to create that, and includes a video of the effect. Here it is:

https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation

Comment: if you consider that the right answer, make sure you accept the answer as right and vote on it. That'll guarantee that in the future other people answer your questions again!

Comment: I just think it is a component given by Apple or some open project when I also found it in Gmail App.

Comment: @Kuroro Apple doesn't provide this as a built in component. What happens is that people tend to copy others a lot in iOS land.. if somebody comes up with a cool idea (like this side menu), it doesn't take long for other apps to popup with the same thing.

Comment: Another great alternative: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck .

Comment: And another: https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Answer (score 1):

There is no already made component to do that given by Apple.

I would say it's just an UIView under the main one that is slided on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start from [here](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/open-source-library-for-stacking-customized-ipad-uiviewcontrollers/) and work your way out. The basic idea is very much there.

Comment: @Eimantas Corrected. Strange!