# Is it a UIScrollView for facebook when switch view?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

[image]

I also see it at path http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/path/id403639508?mt=8,  so think is from apple official sdk,  but do not know what it is ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the Facebook app uses the Master Detail Xcode template, but if you are planning on creating an app similar in design I would recommend using the [MFSideMenu](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mfsidemenu) iOS component.