# Creating a slide in side view controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to know how to create a 'side' View Controller. They are becoming increasingly popular...

Apps such as Facebook and Words with Friends use these on IOS, these are two extremely popular apps so will not upload a picture for this.

When clicking on the = icon in the top navigation a side navigation/menu theme view controller is shown on the side, whilst the navigation controller current view controller is moved slightly to the other side. For example, you can still see the original view controller slightly on the right side, whilst a list of available options are shown.

Does anyone know how this would be achieved or a tutorial of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This github project seems to be what you are looking for. Similar to what Facebook has:

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

[image: github page picture example]

Comment: simplest control to implement

Comment: I actually went through a whole load of these back when the question was posted and found this ECSlidingViewController and this was what I went with, exactly the functionality I was looking for and easiest to implement in the way I needed. Thanks