# How to style uitableview to create pretty menu

Tags: ios, facebook, menu, styles

I've been working on app, that has side-menu. I've been inspired by other apps, and I want my menu to look similar to theirs. Here are some examples (steam app menu, fb menu)
[image: FB Menu][image: Steam Menu]

Basically my question is, what kind of outlets are used in this menu? My first thought was, that those are tableviews with sections and static cells. However, even if they are tableviews, I've got no idea how to style my tableview that way. All I came up with, was this crappy design :D
[image: My menu]

I would be very glad, if someone could show me right way :) Thank you guys

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

Comment: Ender,thx, but I already checked it.. It concerns only technique of menu coming from the side, which I have already done.. My question is purely of design

Comment: Take a look at the project mentioned by @rossbeale, it looks a good fb menu clone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You look on the right path.  Unfortunately it is simply down to design aspects and the assets you use.

[This project](https://github.com/gresrun/GHSidebarNav) recreates the menu in a very similar way to Facebook's.

Comment: Thanks alot.. I'll give it a try, although I'm pretty noob at xCode, so without storyboard or xib it will be hard :D

Answer (score 7):

There are alot of similar open source controls available.

Please check the below links:

1. [**SASlidemenu**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu)
2. [**JWSlidemenu**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jwslidemenu)
3. [**CHSlidecontroller**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/chslidecontroller)
4. [**NVSlidemenucontroller**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nvslidemenucontroller)
5. [**DDMenucontroller**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddmenucontroller)

[image: SASlider] - [image: JWSlider]

[image: CHSlider] - [image: NVSlider]

[image: DDSlider]

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer too Midhun, I upvoted it, because you show different styles of tableviews. I however accepted first answer, because it gives me source for same style Im looking for. But thx anyway!