# I want to add multiple sections in one section of a uitableview. How can i do that

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My functionality is like records will appear categorized by date  which can be further expanded .

Comment: better u can create menu tableview like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437413/how-to-style-uitableview-to-create-pretty-menu

Comment: if u want to add tableview inside of tableview cell see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

You have to Add another table in section. and also handle numberOfRow,Section by its name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom cell in order to divide a single cell into different parts.