# How to make a "sidebar menu" with rubymotion?

Tags: iphone, rubymotion

What libraries are available to allow for sidebar menu functionality in RubyMotion?

[image: sidebar menu]

Something very similar to this app design, I was wondering if it was possible using RubyMotion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try some of the answers detailed here:

[What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

Some of the suggested ones:

- https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck
- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtrevealsidebar
- https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Some of these may be CocoaPods and I would recommend using those versions. Just run `pod search X` (with X being the name of the library) to find out.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize Facebook had the same thing (as I'm not a FB'er). Very insightful and helpful response, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem ... hope it works for you!