# Can you tell me what is the name of the control that is used for screen navigation like that in Facebook app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

If there is an example it will be very thoughtful of you.

[image: Facebook app for iPhone]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a native control. There are libraries though. Take a look at [JTRevealSidebar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jtrevealsidebar).

Answer (score 1):

Check IIViewDeckController. Here's github link: http://www.github.com/inferis/viewdeck/