# How to make the UIView function like UIScrollView (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I have a class named **Topic**. And inside that topic I can create (and delete) **Messages**. I need to show the messages in a view that can be scrolled/swiped either right or left (Right to show the older messages, and left to go back to the newer messages). Imagine an image collection that can be scrolled sideways in a `ScrollView`, that how this should look like. Since the messages is being add by the user, I can't use `UIImage`. I am thinking of the approach that I need to add use `UIView` instead of a `ScrollView`, now my problem is how can I make my `UIView` function as a `ScrollView` in terms of displaying data?

please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use UIScrollView?

Comment: This sounds like a really backward question. If you need the functionality of a UIScrollView why would you use anything else?

Comment: if I use `UIScrollView`, once I swipe the screen, the data that I want to display keeps scrolling to the screen, I want to make the data stop at one by one when it's body is already fitted on the screen just like when set of images in a `ScrollView` like this one on this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_CagcT0dOc

Comment: Well, you can actually turn off the scrolling in a scrollView ON/OFF whenever you want to (scrollEnabled). If you add a swipeGestureRecognizer you can scroll the view in code, have a look at the setContentOffset:animated: method.

Comment: @nickfalk by usingContentOffset:animated, I can set the size of the content that will be loaded and displayed on the screen using `ScrollView` when I do swipeGesture, am I right?

Comment: enable pagination on the scroll view.

Comment: another related question, can I add views inside `UIScrollView?` if yes? what function can I use?

Comment: @Fogmeister, i tried this and it somehow work. but it does not load the exact view that I want to see, is this the time that I need to use `setContentOffset`?

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you want to do. And yes, you can add views inside a scrollview. That's how it is used. It's just another UIView subclass. Explain what you are trying to achieve then we'll be able to help better.

Comment: @Fogmeister, i just obtained what I want by adding `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;` thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to use gesture recognition. Check that user is swiping left or swiping right. after Identifying that you can change UIView with animation. I hope you can get me. This can be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by enabling paging on the scroll view, by setting the following property to YES as shown:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

This will make the scroll view scroll one page at a time.