# open different viewcontroller in master-detail application in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using master-detail application and in master tableview I have 4 active entries.
By tapping on cell in master tableview I want to open new viewcontroller in detail view.

And I want to do for all 4 active cells.

I am new to iphone.
so give me some idea.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for master and detail your can user one of them

1)  [Jasidepanels](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels)
2)  [Saslidemenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/saslidemenu)
3)  [Jwslidemenu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jwslidemenu)
4)  [Msnavigationpaneviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/msnavigationpaneviewcontroller)
5)  [Bzslideout](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bzslideout)
6)  [Hhtablistcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hhtablistcontroller-vertical-tab-view-controller)
7)  [Swrevealviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swrevealviewcontroller)
8)  [FacebookMenu](https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation)   
 
9)  [ViewDesk](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
10) [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)and 
 
see this [What's the best way to develop a sideswipe menu like the one in Facebook's new iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

and one of the best solution is

1)   http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1 
2)  http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/03/master-detail-ipad-mobile-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

First you create 4 view controller. then you can use segue (keep Control and drag from one of the cell in Table to one of view controller.the Style of segue should be "Replace". do this for all of 4 cells and 4 view controller.