# How to Create a Slide-Out Navigation Panel in ios

Tags: ios

[image] 1. How to Create a Slide-Out Navigation Panel in ios

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i

Answer (score 8):

One of the best sliding panels, that also supports **UIKit Dynamics** was created by **Eric Horacek** and it is called `MSDynamicsDrawerViewController`. It is available on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController).

There are many other open source libraries available online. Pick the one that suits your needs the best.

- [MasterDetailController](https://github.com/styrken/MasterDetailController)
- [CCKFNavDrawer](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer)
- [GHSidebarNav](https://github.com/gresrun/GHSidebarNav)
- [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)
- [ADSlidingViewController](https://github.com/adamdebono/ADSlidingViewController)
- [YASlidingViewController](https://github.com/ThomasConner/YASlidingViewController)
- [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController)
- [DDSlidingPanels](https://github.com/deem0n/DDSlidingPanels)
- [MSSlidingPanelController](https://github.com/SebastienMichoy/MSSlidingPanelController)

*All you have to do, is read the documentation and embed the library in your project.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list! It has been a great help!

Comment: To create something like the slider of Gmail App, what 2 libraries do you suggest? ( kindly only suggest 2)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a difficult thing to create that. there is a lot of source code available on git. you can use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)
[REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController)

or you can follow this tutorial
[Create Facebook like navigation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path),
[ios-Slide Out Navigation](http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/ios-slide-out-navigation-code/)

Answer (score 0):

Itisn't a hard task once i found this tutorial, there are various other methods too followed as in Dribble. But the easiest method is to follow this tutorial.
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
Thanks to APPCODA..