# SlideMenu Like Facebook Without Using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm currently working on a project that is being developed without using a single XIB and it is a huge project. We are gonna release a new version by changing the user interface. It require for me to build a Slider Menu like we find in facebook app. I have plenty of sample coding which do it and every project uses Storyboard to set it up. My question is,

**Is it possible to develop that without using Storyboard?**

Thanks.

Comment: Check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i

Comment: how about a library like this: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: I use the https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu, it's easy to understand it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply everyone. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links might help you :

https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will have a look at it.

Comment: you got your answer or not??

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Thanks for your answer and I finally manage to use MFSideMenu.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the following link:-

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

This is one of the best slide menu example code I have used.