# How do you create a slider menu with only xibs in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xib

How do you create a slider menu with only xibs and no storyboards?

http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/slide-out-navigation/

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115884/slidemenu-like-facebook-without-using-storyboard

Comment: see this also http://www.2bdoc.com/video/ios-slide-menu-tutorial-xib-sliding-menu-with-both-left-and-right-menus-from-zero-project-v115029.html

Comment: https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer