# What's the best way to develop a side swipe menu in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios8

Side swipe menus are pretty popular in iOS applications, so I was wondering if there are any options offered in iOS 8 that allow for it to be implemented in a more straight forward way (like how you can load a screen modally with one click).

[This was helpful but it's three years old at this point.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i)

I've found tutorials on how to do it ([AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) and [UXMag](http://uxmag.com/articles/adapting-ui-to-ios-7-the-side-menu)), but most of them are at least a year old as well.

I'm wondering if iOS 8 offers new functionality that would make the design a little bit easier?

I've read some about the split view controller that was enhanced in iOS 8. Could that be used to the same effect as the example shown below?

[image: Kindle app]

Comment: I don't really see this as an opinion based question. I'm asking if, what was a work around before, has been included by default in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Apple introduced UITableViewRowAction in iOS8.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html

Comment: This looks like it's for individual rows in a table as opposed to an entire menu that can be swiped.

Comment: So you are just looking to present a full VC using a UIGesture?

Comment: A UI gesture and button, yeah. In the image above the menu slides out from the left side and covers the main VC.