# How to create custom slide menu without third party library.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I want to implement slide menu in my iOS app like drawer (Andriod). I went through a tutorial, but all of them are using third party libraries. Is there any possibility to create a custom slide menu. I tried to create it with the following code, but it's only working with xib file:

```
- (IBAction)sidemenu:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        view.frame = self.view.frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureLeftAction:)];
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    }];
 }

- (void)SwipGestureAction
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureRightAction:)];
    swiperight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
}

#pragma mark AddSwipeGestureLeftAndRight
- (void)SwipGestureRightAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        view.frame = self.view.frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipGestureLeftAction:)];
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    }];
}

- (void)SwipGestureLeftAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    }];
}
```

Comment: see this bro , it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989020/whats-the-best-way-to-develop-a-sideswipe-menu-like-the-one-in-facebooks-new-i

Comment: ok sir  let me check this one

Comment: sir if i follow that link it will push view on left, but what i want is view should be appear on the current view. its should not be push. like drawer in android?

Comment: @Bhavinn Thanks sir its a nice tutorial but i am working on objective c right now?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir is there any tutorial which i should follow for this task?

Comment: As you said, there are many open source libraries that do that. Why don't you pick one and read the source code?

Comment: @phi sir all these examples uses third party libraries and if i used those libraries than they create some problem some other view controller in my project

Comment: Yes, I wrote that you can *read* the source code, not *use* the library :) As a side note, maybe you can also focus on finding out why using a library would create some problem in your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have for you:

I made a super class for all my slide menus in all projects. It manages the showing and hiding of the slide menu, and handles orientation changes. It slides in from left on top of the current view, and it partially obscures the remainder of the view with a dark transparent background.
If you ever need other behaviour (like pushing out the current view) just override the animation part.
My slide menu is a Singleton because in our applications we only use one slide menu on every screen.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IS_SlideMenu_View : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIView* transparentBgView;
    BOOL hidden;
    int lastOrientation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *menuContainerV;

+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (BOOL)isShown;
- (void)hideSlideMenu;
- (void)showSlideMenu;

@end


#import "IS_SlideMenu_View.h"

@implementation IS_SlideMenu_View

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static id _sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });
    
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        
        transparentBgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [transparentBgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.6]];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:0];
        transparentBgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognized:)];
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognized:)];
        [transparentBgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [transparentBgView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
        
        [self addSubview:transparentBgView];
        
        frame.size.width = 280;
        self.menuContainerV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        CALayer *l = self.menuContainerV.layer;
        l.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        l.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 0);
        l.shadowOpacity = 1;
        l.masksToBounds = NO;
        l.shadowRadius = 10;
        self.menuContainerV.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        
        [self addSubview: self.menuContainerV];
        hidden = YES;
    }
    
    //----- SETUP DEVICE ORIENTATION CHANGE NOTIFICATION -----
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:device];
    
    lastOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    
    return self;
}

//********** ORIENTATION CHANGED **********
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];    
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        NSLog(@"%ld",orientation);
        if(!hidden && lastOrientation != orientation){
            [self hideSlideMenu];
            hidden = YES;
            lastOrientation = orientation;
        }
    }
}

- (void)showSlideMenu {
    UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height);
    
    [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-window.frame.size.width, 0)];
    
    [window addSubview:self];
//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:1];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Show complete!");
        hidden = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)gestureRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [self hideSlideMenu];
    } else if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        static CGFloat startX;
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            startX = [recognizer locationInView:self.window].x;
        } else
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            CGFloat touchLocX = [recognizer locationInView:self.window].x;
            if (touchLocX < startX) {
                [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(touchLocX - startX, 0)];
            }
        } else
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            [self hideSlideMenu];
        }
    }
}

- (void)hideSlideMenu
{
    UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.window.frame.size.width, 0)];
        [transparentBgView setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
        [self.menuContainerV setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        
//        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Hide complete!");
    }];
}

- (BOOL)isShown
{
    return !hidden;
}

@end
```

Subclasses only need to add subviews to the `menuContainerV` view, and manage them.

#### An example:

I created a subclass that has an header view and a table view as its content. I created the content view in a xib, and the owner of the xib is this subclass. This way I can bind outlets to the xib.

```
#import "IS_SlideMenu_View.h"

@interface CC_SlideMenu_View : IS_SlideMenu_View<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

...

@end
```

When the slide menu gets instantiated I load the xib and add the content view to the menuContainerV view.

```
#import "CC_SlideMenu_View.h"

@implementation CC_SlideMenu_View

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UIView *v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CC_SlideMenu_View" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
        v.frame = self.menuContainerV.bounds;
        [self.menuContainerV addSubview:v];
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

...

@end
```

The result is something like [this](http://a1.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple7/v4/bb/42/b1/bb42b1f9-b229-8f6c-77ef-75b7ea9f012e/screen322x572.jpeg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, i tried to implement it

Comment: sir are you using xib's in your project?, because it seem that code is written according to xib?

Comment: You can use xibs for separate views or view controllers and the same time storyboard for other view controllers. Xibs and storyboards are not mutually exclusive. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes sir thanks, i was afraid to use both together. its fine now