# Awkward landscape keyboard in portrait?

Tags: ios, landscape

I'm inserting a view directly into the UIWindow of an application.  If the view I was in previously had a keyboard up and was in landscape I sometimes get this view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/plutA.jpg

I have tried printing out all the details for the UIWindow's layer and all sublayers and none of them appear to have a transform on them.  Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Never seen anything like that before, but keyboard orientation seems to be tied to status bar orientation so this might fix the issue

```
// This Controls KEYBOARD orientation even if you have the status bar hidden
//
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWindow doesn't handle auto-rotation or autoresizing - only UIViewControllers do that.  You have to manage the rotation/scale of any views attached directly to the window yourself.

See [Orientation in a UIView added to a UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508630/orientation-in-a-uiview-added-to-a-uiwindow)