# Screen rotation from device orientation and a new UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, screen, orientation

What is the safest and most effective way place a new UIView within the bounds of the App's UIWindow on the top of the view stack when a screen rotation from Portrait to Landscape occurs? *Also, when returning from Landscape to Portrait, to remove this subview.*

Basically the App is created as most are:

> -UIWindow:
>
> --UIView
>
> ---All subviews (including a tabview controller)

I would like to create:

> -UIWindow:
>
> --UIView (new, to be placed on top)
>
> --UIView
>
> ---All subviews (and triggered by a view controller in here)

Is this wrong? There is surprisingly little documentation to help do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the a working solution. Might you offer a better one?

```
    ArtsDayAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ArtsDayAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIView *landscapeView;

    if (!landscapeView) {
        landscapeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    }

    [landscapeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    ..add various views..
    [appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:landscapeView];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a view controller to hold all of your subviews you can just use the rotation functions that will be called for you:

willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
and
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

So lets say you use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation you check

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{
    [yourView removeFromSuperView];
}
else
{
    [self.view addSubView: yourView];
}
```

Comment: where in the app structure would I do this? The app delegate?

Comment: I took from your initial post that you wanted to do this within a viewcontroller so you would put this logic within the function "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation" which is a part of any UIViewController. In the code above "self" refers to the view controller. You can see the official documentation here [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) This function will be called when your app rotates on you and it will pass you in the orientation that will be changed to that you can use my code to check against.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying, but because the app uses TabView, the delegate is what creates the UITabViewController and places within the first view i.e. the app delegate's 'Root View Controller'. I say this, because it is my belief that any subviews are limited by the bounds for their superview. Is this right? Can I in fact subview a full screen view?

Comment: I think I am understanding more about what your problem is since I didn't realize you had a tab bar. The application delegate has a function - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation which looks like you might be able to intercept at the app delegate level and then add a full screen view directly on your application's window (which would also cover the tab bar) and then when it rotates out you can remove it.

Comment: so there is no way of calling a superview function to take care of it?

Comment: I think you need to have some location where you keep a reference to this view that you are going to be added or removed from and I would think the app delegate would be the best spot since you will have direct access to the window(you can easily access it anywhere else if you wanted). So your app delegate creates the tab controller and its view gets added to the window. When the app rotates you want to add a view to cover the tab view which would be added on as a full screen subview to your window and removing if ([coverview removeFromSuperview];) when you rotate back.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960988/202451

It should bring you closer to doing custom things like that