# How to add a fullscreen subview to the current UIWindow in objective c which will change according to the device orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, uiwindow

I want to add a temporary view over the current presented viewcontroller which covers the entire screen.After some research I found that I should add this screen as a subview of current UIWindow.I used the following code.But the view is not covering the entire screen.

```
`UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
//mainWindow.frame=self.view.frame;
_autoPlayViewBackground.frame=self.view.frame;
_autoPlayViewBackground.hidden=NO;
[mainWindow addSubview:_autoPlayViewBackground];`
```

This code is giving a window towards a side.Any help would be a great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orientation in a UIView added to a UIWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508630/orientation-in-a-uiview-added-to-a-uiwindow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myView];
```

Make sure whatever you want to show will be added in `UIView` which is `myView`. *This is very important step.*

Comment: Can i do the last step like `[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview: _autoPlayViewBackground];` ?

Comment: @abhi1992 : no, add `_autoPlayViewBackground ` in one UIView and add that UIView to window... ***Read my last statement in answer again***

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.But the actual problem was with the autolayout of the subview.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
_autoPlayViewBackground.frame=self.view.frame;
```

into

```
_autoPlayViewBackground.view.frame = window.bounds; // or use window .frame
_autoPlayViewBackground.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try given method to show AutoPlayBgView in full screen

```
- (void) showAutoPlayBgViewInFullScreen
{
    UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    // set frame of auto play bg view
    _autoPlayViewBackground.frame = window.frame;

    // add auto play bg view as subview in window
    [window addSubview: _autoPlayViewBackground];
}
```

Hope this code will help you.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow this pattern:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
subView.frame = rect;

[parentView addSubview:subView];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `-[UIScreen mainScreen]` has been deprecated on iOS 16.0. Also if you are considering about supporting Split View or Stage Manager, avoid using `-[UIScreen mainScreen]`.

Answer (score 1):

To add a fullscreen subview to the current `UIWindow` you can do like this.

```
    UIView *viewBg=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [viewBg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.f green:1/255.f blue:1/255.f alpha:0.4]];
    [self.view.window addSubview:viewBg];
```