# View on top of everything: UIWindow subview VS UIViewController subview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uialertview, uiwindow

In order to make a `UIView` on top of all views like the behavior of `UIAlertView`, the best way I see is by putting it in the app window, which is by adding the view to:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]
```

However, the downside I found is that it doesn't automatically take in rotation. In order for it to take in rotation, the best way to do is by adding the view on current AppDelegate `window.navigationController`/`rootViewController`, however, by doing this it will no longer be on top of everything. Let say when view is displaying and there is a modalViewController popup, the modal view will certainly cover up the view.

My question is, is it possible to add subview to the top most window *and* support orientation? Do I need two set of Nib file in this case? How `UIAlertView` does the magic to combine the topmost & orientation support? When I look into the `UIAlertView.h`, I see there is actually 2 `UIWindows`, once is called `originalWindow` and another called `dimWindow`. Is there a place where I can find the source code for `UIAlertView.m`?

Answer (score 15):

The best solution I've found is to create a transparent container view, add that container to the window, and place your alert inside the container. You may then register for `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` to receive rotation events and transform the container; this allows you to independently manipulate the frame of the alert:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
     ...
     self.container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
     [self.container addSubview:self.alertView];
     [self.window addSubview:self.container];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                              selector:@selector(statusBarWillRotate:) 
                                                  name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification 
                                                object:nil];
     ...
}
...
- (void)statusBarWillRotate:(NSNotification *)theNotification
{
    CGFloat rotation = 0;
    switch ([notification[UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] intValue])
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            rotation = -M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            rotation = M_PI_2;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            rotation = M_PI;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: 
        default:
            rotation = 0;
            break;
    }
    CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
    CGSize rotatedSize = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.window.bounds, rotationTransform).size;
    [UIView animationWithDuration:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration
                       animations:^{
         self.container.transform = rotationTransform;
         // Transform invalidates the frame, so use bounds/center
         self.container.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, rotatedSize.width, rotatedSize.height);
         self.container.center = CGPointMake(self.window.bounds.size.width / 2, self.window.bounds.size.height / 2);
     }];
}
```

You can, if you really want, create an entirely new window with its `windowLevel` property set to `UIWindowLevelAlert`, which will guarantee that the window remain above all other views, including the keyboard, but window management gets a littly tricky. The above solution should suffice for most needs.

The problem with simply adding a view controller's view to a window is that it is not guaranteed to receive all the rotation and `view[Will|Did][Disa|A]ppear:` messages unless it is added to the view controller *hierarchy* via `addChildViewController:` on the root view controller.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. I'm not able to register touches in that top most container view. UIButtons doesn't work, for example.

Comment: @asendra Sounds like your window isn't the key window, but you may want to post your own question with more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Only the first subview of `UIWindow` gets told about orientation changes. (< iOS8)

Your question is very similar to this one:

[Multiple views in a UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189078/multiple-views-in-a-uiwindow)

As the answer there says, you can register for notifications of orientation changes and handle relayout of your 'on top' subview that way.

Comment: How to register the view to the device to receive rotation event? It's not View Controller, so there is no delegate functions for it. Do I have to catch the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification to change to corresponding orientation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, I am explaining in a few steps.

1. Start With a `UIViewController` inherited class instead of `UIView`,  Lets say class named  `TopViewController` inherited by `UIViewController`
2. Since you you can not register device/interface rotation in UIView inherited class, the `TopViewController` class  which is inherited from  `UIViewController` has methods responding to View Rotation Events.  Rotation events can be captured now.
3. At last you can put the `TopViewController` view on the top of `UIWindow` by using the same method that you mentioned in your question .

   ```
   [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:(TopViewController object).view];
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: UIViewController's view property wont rotate also. Unfortunately. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html