# Put a view on top landscape support

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am using the following code to create a view and put it on top:

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect viewRect = mainWindow.frame;
topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.4]];
[mainWindow addSubview:topView];
```

It works perfectly but my problem is if I write anything one the view(like using a Label) and my device is in a landscape position, the text is in vertical position. I've attached a picture to make it more clear. Is there any way to fix it?[image]

EDIT: if I use UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController instead of mainWindow, I will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fix it without adding the given view to a View Controller (`UIWindow` was never meant to handle rotation, and has no logic to do so).

The wonky view rotation results you're experiencing are actually the result of UIView's default `autoresizingMask`'s

```
topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.4]];
[topViewsetAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

Comment: how can I get the top viewcontroller then?

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController`

Comment: When I use the rootViewController instead of the mainWindow, the gray frame is vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: @AliBZ I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Ah!  That has to do with your autoresizingmasks.  Hold on, let me edit my answer to fix that

Comment: @AliBZ Are you using Auto Layout?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[View on top of everything: UIWindow subview VS UIViewController subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774495/view-on-top-of-everything-uiwindow-subview-vs-uiviewcontroller-subview)

Basically, only the first subview of the main window gets rotation events, so you have to do it some other way.