# Add a UIView above all, even the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, popupwindow

I want to display, above any other views, even the navigation bar, a kind of "pop-up" view that looks like this:

- full screen black background with a 0.5 alpha to see the other `UIViewController` underneath.
- a `UIView` window in the middle with some information, (a calendar if you want to know everything).

To do that, I've created a UIViewController that contains the two `UIViews` (background and window), and I'm trying to display it. I've tried a simple `[mySuperVC addSubview:myPopUpVC.view]`, but I still have the navigation bar above.

I've tried to present it as a modal, but the `UIViewController` underneath disappears, and I lose my transparency effect.

Any idea to do this, I'm sure it's quite simple...

Thanks!

Comment: Add a subview on your application window. Handling orientation changes can be tricky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774495/view-on-top-of-everything-uiwindow-subview-vs-uiviewcontroller-subview

Answer (score 221):

You can do that by adding your view directly to the keyWindow:

```
UIView *myView = /* <- Your custom view */;
UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:myView];
```

**UPDATE -- For Swift 4.1 and above**

```
let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
currentWindow?.addSubview(myView)
```

**UPDATE for iOS13 and above**

`keyWindow` is deprecated. You should use the following:

```swift
UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately if you are in landscape mode you need to rotate the view. I'm not sure I know how to do that properly.

Comment: Yes, I'm only in landscape mode and myView appears with a 90 degrees rotation. Seems to be what they're talking about here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774495/view-on-top-of-everything-uiwindow-subview-vs-uiviewcontroller-subview

Comment: The orientation problem happens on pre-iOS8 devices, for which this solution sadly doesn't work.

Comment: @NicolasRoy Autolayout will help

Comment: Adding to the window will make it appear in all your view controllers. So if you want it on a specific view controller add your view to the Navigation Bar itself as @dalef says below: [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];

Comment: When I try this, it shows up on the screen but quickly goes away when the screen loads. I tried adding it to viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, and viewWillAppear with the same results.

Comment: it doesn't cover tab bar. Any solution for that?

Comment: It also does not covers the status bar

Answer (score 142):

`[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];` is what you really want

Comment: You need to set the frame

Comment: This does not work with a child view controller's view. Changing the navigation bar's z-level (as Nam suggests) works also with child view controllers.

Comment: It looks to ma more elegant solution than adding view to Key window. As this ensures added view, moves along the animation of base view. Because if view is added on key window it doesnt come with animation and has to be removed seperately if you want to dismiss the controller.

Answer (score 123):

Here is a simple elegant solution that is working for me. You can set the z position of the navigation bar to below the view:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
```

Just remember to set it back to 0 when done.

Comment: Works great for me too. It would be great to mention that zPosition should be set back to value 0 (you just mention that It should be set back when done). And I have tabBar (from TabBarController in my screen too. I tried to set zPosition but when returning to 0 value tabBar wasn't still visible. So for tabBar it's better to use isHidden property.

Comment: Don't work with accessibility. Panning over the view won't focus it.

Comment: This sets the navigation controller behind everything though, making it invisible..?

Comment: Is added view is UIImageview and we apply pinch zoom In it , even setting zPosition , the navigation bar button stops working

Answer (score 61):

Swift versions for the checked response :

**Swift 4 :**

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(view)
```

**Swift 3.1 :**

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.frame 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(view)
```

Answer (score 27):

Dalef great solution in swift:

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(view)
```

Answer (score 24):

Add you view as the subview of NavigationController.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview: overlayView)]
```

You can also add it over the window:

```
UIView *view = /* Your custom view */;
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[window addSubview:view];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Over view is coming but, when add a button couldn't get button action or set    custom label text on the overView

Answer (score 18):

@Nam's answer works great if you just want to display your custom view **but if your custom view needs user interaction you need to disable interaction for the `navigationBar`**.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Like said in Nam's answer don't forget to reverse these changes:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 0
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

---

You can do this in a better way with an extension:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func toggle() {
        if self.layer.zPosition == -1 {
            self.layer.zPosition = 0
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            self.layer.zPosition = -1
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

And simply use it like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.toggle()
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift version of @Nicolas Bonnet 's answer:

```
    var popupWindow: UIWindow?

func showViewController(controller: UIViewController) {
    self.popupWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    controller.view.frame = self.popupWindow!.bounds
    self.popupWindow!.rootViewController = controller
    self.popupWindow!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func viewControllerDidRemove() {
    self.popupWindow?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.popupWindow = nil
}
```

Don't forget that the window must be a strong property, because the original answer leads to an immediate deallocation of the window

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to create a new UIWindow:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
window.rootViewController = viewController;
window.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
window.opaque = NO;
window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelCFShareCircle;
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then you can manage your view in an other UIViewController.
To remove the windows:

```
[window removeFromSuperview];
window = nil;
```

hope that will help!

Comment: Thanks, but I think something is missing because nothing appears :/

Answer (score 6):

There is more than one way to do it:

1- Add your `UIView` on `UIWindow` instead of adding it on `UIViewController`. This way it will be on top of everything.

```
   [[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] addSubview:view];
```

2- Use custom transition that will keep your UIViewController showing in the back with a 0.5 alpha

For that I recommend you look at this: https://github.com/Citrrus/BlurryModalSegue

Answer (score 4):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10

```
var spinnerView: UIView? //This is your view

spinnerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
//Based on your requirement change width and height like self.view.bounds.size.width
spinnerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
//        self.view.addSubview(spinnerView)
let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
currentWindow?.addSubview(spinnerView!)
```

In **Objective C**

UIView *spinnerView;//This is your view

```
self.spinnerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height)];  
//Based on your requirement change width and height like self.view.bounds.size.width
self.spinnerView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
// [self.view addSubview:self.spinnerView];
UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:self.spinnerView];
```

This can work either Portrait OR Landscape mode.

One more simple code is:

```
yourViewName.layer.zPosition = 1//Change your view name
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note if you want add view in Full screen then only use below code**

Add these **extension** of **UIViewController**

```
public extension UIViewController {
   internal func makeViewAsFullScreen() {
      var viewFrame:CGRect = self.view.frame
      if viewFrame.origin.y > 0 || viewFrame.origin.x > 0 {
        self.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
      }
   }
}
```

Continue as normal adding process of subview

Now use in adding **UIViewController's viewDidAppear**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     self.makeViewAsFullScreen()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a UIViewController subclass containing a "Container View" that embeds your others view controllers.
You'll then be able to add the navigation controller inside the Container View (using the embed relationship segue for example).

See [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(yourView, at: 1)
```

This method works with xcode 9.4 , iOS 11.4

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setZPosition:-0.1];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 35, 35)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
[self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
self.navigationController.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setZPosition:0.0];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a subview to the first window with the UITextEffectsWindow type. To the first, because custom keyboards add their UITextEffectsWindow, and if you add a subview to it this won't work correctly.
Also, you cannot add a subview to the last window because the keyboard, for example, is also a window and you can`t present from the keyboard window.
So the best solution I found is to add subview (or even push view controller) to the first window with UITextEffectsWindow type, this window covers accessory view, navbar - everything.

```
let myView = MyView()
myView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

guard let textEffectsWindow = NSClassFromString("UITextEffectsWindow") else { return }
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { window in
    window.isKind(of: textEffectsWindow)
}
window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(myView)
```