# How to create a view above navigation bar or other screen content?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to have a view above the navigation bar, or above any screen content if there isn't a navigation bar on that screen, so that it essentially reduces the height of everything else and doesn't cover any content.  I also would like this view allow interaction (i.e. if its tapped, it would do something).

I have tried 
`UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(view)` but that just overlays the view.

Here is a visualization:
[image: View above navigation bar.]

Comment: check this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850436/add-a-uiview-above-all-even-the-navigation-bar

Comment: @Uma yeah, I was looking at that and tried a few things there, but that is focused on overlay versus side by side.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817762/1106035

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think of it in terms of above, think of it as beside - a sibling view.

So, create your own root view controller with that view and a container view below it, then add your 'normal' root navigation controller (or whatever) as a child view controller into the container view.

Comment: I went with this way and it works out pretty nicely.  I was initially running into issues with the navigation controller in the container view not reacting to the status bar, but I just had to fiddle with autolayout to get it working.  Now, when I toggle the red bar at the top, the navigation bar moves correctly, but the nav controller's child view doesn't get pushed all the way down.  I might have to ask another question, but before I do, any quick thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: is anything in a scroll view auto adjusting insets that you don't actually want?

Comment: Yeah, it's a table view that doesn't seem to be moving as far down as the navigation bar above it.

Comment: You need to turn off auto inset on the view controller

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that.  If you're bored, I have another SO question that I just submitted because of a problem I've run into going down this route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309298/in-a-container-view-a-navigation-controllers-navigation-bar-not-resizing-to-in

Comment: This is the best answer in the whole SO!! I've struggled with moving ViewController frames, while adding a subview to the windows, but they broke as soon as a modal view appeared (a Picker/SMS composer/incoming phone call).. this one is the best. And it's the way it's meant to behave.