# In a container view, a navigation controller's navigation bar not resizing to include status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicontainerview

I have created an application which needs to have a bar above the navigation bar and other views.  To accomplish this, I am using a view controller with a view for the top bar, and then a container view for everything else.  Sometimes, the top bar needs to be hidden.  I'm using autolayout to hide the top bar (set its height to 0), and the container view expands to fill the screen (container top equal to the top bar bottom). The container view contains a navigation controller because I need a navigation bar below the top bar sometimes.  When I start the app, this all works fine as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the navigation bar stays the desired height, which is expanded to include the status bar

However, when the top bar is tapped, I use a segue to present (not push) a view controller from my root view controller (not the container), and then I look at the same screen with the navigation bar, the navigation bar is no longer extended and it overlaps the status bar as seen below:

[image]

Why would presenting a view controller break this?  And then how could I rectify this or prevent it?

One possible solution I could do is present a view controller from within the container view, that works, I would just have to set the current view controller in the container to a delegate of the root controller, so that when the top bar is tapped, it tells the view controller in the container to present the new view controller.  This would not be my first option however, especially if there are other scenarios which cause this problem.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` off for all of your child view controllers and manage the insets (or setup so they aren't required) yourself. By default `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is on for all view controllers (which is what you want for 'full screen' presented VCs.

At the moment you see controllers almost randomly updating to reorganise themselves for the scroll insets as the VC hierarchy changes.

I'd probably turn `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` off for all VCs (apart from root) and change your header view so that it's full height or status bar height (which should be the `length` of the `topLayoutGuide` of the root VC). When collapsed to status bar height your header view could also change colour to match that of the current top VC.

Comment: Problem 1: When displaying the header view and a navigation bar, the navigation bar is only 44 points, is there anyway to make it 64 points even though it technically isn't covered by the status bar?

Comment: Problem 2: If the initial view controller is the one with the container and the header, how would you recommend keeping track of the header's color so that depending on what view controller I'm in, I can change its color from any view controller?

Comment: 1 you'd need to subclass, not so easy... 2 you could implement the navigation controller delegate

Comment: Okay, I solved the status bar problem by using autolayout to add a gap of 20 points between the header view and container view.  Then, I set the background to the color of the container view background, or the container view's navigation bar.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to vote and mark answers if they helped :)