# How can I render a VisualElement before the NavigationPage toolbar?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Using NavigationPage produces views likes this:

```
===== Start of view
<navigation toolbar>
<page content>
===== End of view
```

I want this (pretty much the same thing as [How to create a view above navigation bar or other screen content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35286610/1663774)):

```
===== Start of view
<arbitrary VisualElement>
<navigation toolbar>
<page content>
===== End of view
```

I know this can be done without NavigationPage by using platform-specific navigation controller APIs. However, I would like to use the Xamarin.Forms NavigationPage navigation stack management, meaning that I either need to use NavigationPage or possibly a subclass of NavigationPage.

How can I render a VisualElement before the NavigationPage toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this is not really a setup you would want to do in Xamarin.Forms. It is possible you could look at hiding the NavBar and making your own, but then you would no longer have things like the native back button or toolbar items and need to implement them yourself. This is definitely a case where you likely will want to look at solutions per platform; trying to leverage this in Forms will likely be messy at best.