# How to draw on the entire screen with all UI elements on top in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

I am working on a side project that it needs to draw on whatever it's displaying on the current screen. However, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` only gets me the content of that view only but the entire screen. The drawing view contains many more UI elements and those are not getting drawn. I am just wondering how I should handle it.

Here is how I used to get the current context(self is an instance of UIView):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to have a UIView that covers the entire screen. Then you can draw in the entire UIView. Which UIView are you using now?

To create a UIView that covers the entire screen, you should either add a subview to the main window (`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`) or if you're in a `navigationController` add a view as overlay to the view hierarchy (`[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView]`). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850436/add-a-uiview-above-all-even-the-navigation-bar)

Comment: I was thinking it too complicated! I was trying capture the whole screen and draw it inside the `drawRect`. Your way makes more sense. Most importantly, it's efficient. It won't drive the CPU crazy.

Comment: BTW, `[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` can do the trick. But, it's just used for capturing the screen. Worse, it's not efficient.