# How to overlay a View controller above all others

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a View Controller with some buttons. These buttons are animated and move around the screen.

When one of them is pressed, I want to segue to another view controller, and still have them there on top of it.

Both the segued view controller and the buttons should still be accessible, meaning  the user should be able to interact with them.

How can I overlay the view controller with the buttons over all the other buttons?

I have tried to create a view controller with a container view and the buttons on top of it, and have other view controllers in the container, but when I try to segue to another view controller, it covers the buttons.

Comment: Well, think about an example where this actually happens: a navigation controller. When you segue to another view controller in a navigation controller, the navigation bar "is still there on top of it". So clearly this is possible readily enough if you use a container view, just as you suggest. You say: "but when I try to segue to another view controller, it covers the buttons". Okay, but then _that_ is the problem you need to solve. A navigation controller's child doesn't cover the nav bar, so you are doing something wrong if you cover your buttons.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817762/1106035

Answer (score 0):

In your second viewcontrollers' viewdidappear, bring the buttons container view to the front using [containerview bringsubviewtofront];