# Show UiView above all views

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show UIView above all navigationBar , status bar.

I tried options like setting navigation z position , adding UIView to UIWindow and adding UIView to NavigationController.

[Add a UIView above all, even the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850436/add-a-uiview-above-all-even-the-navigation-bar)

Nothing worked for me.

My Application is on xcode 9.2 ,swift 4.0 , ios 11.

Comment: @the4kman Views can overlap statusbar.

Comment: @the4kman It's not an overlay, it's a system window. Technically, you can create a window that will be even above the status bar. There are also ways to access it dynamically but I would not advise to do that :)

Comment: @the4kman Not really, I saw apps that were showing notifications messages above the status bar. See https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification. Note that Apple does not force you to show status bar, that's why you can hide it completely for view controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add overlayView on main window:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    let overlayView = UIView()
    overlayView.frame = window.frame
    overlayView.backgroundColor = .red
    window.addSubview(overlayView)
}
```

Comment: I found Problem having constraints on UIView will not work with UIApplication.shared.keyWindow so, I removed constraints and It worked. Please update

Comment: this is perfect, but I tried to press button in the added view but method not getting called! do you know why?

Comment: EnasAZ, please addTarget for UIButton.