# Xamarin.Forms Prism App.xaml can be binded to a ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am building a Xamarin.Forms application with Prism, it shows what Bluetooth devices are connected.

In this application, I need a footer in all the pages showing the connection status of the device.
To do that, I’ve made a static class called `Pen` with the property `IsConnected` updated from the `BleService`.

I also need a button in the footer that is visible when the `Pen` is disconnected and when it is pressed I can call the Connect method of the `BleService`.

For the footer, I’ve made a `ControlTemplate` in the `App.xaml` containing a button.

Now, I’m using Prism and I don’t know how to bind the button to a ViewModel (`App.xaml` does not have a ViewModel) in order to call the Connect Command of the `BleService`.

Answer (score 0):

> The `App.xaml` and `App.aml.cs` files contain the logic required to configure a Prism application and navigate to the root page on startup.

[From the documentation](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/creating-your-first-prism-app.html#appcs)

So you **cant** create a ViewModel for this as it's not a View and this would break the MVVM pattern. Prism is an MVVM framework, that works by loading Views (And their ViewModels) through a Navigation Service. So this approach for a "global" view is not going to work with binding.

Creating a [control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating) is not going to fix this either, it just allows you to have a reusable template defined in the `app.xaml`.

What I would suggest is to either:

1. Add this footer to all views, which is a bit of an overhead.

OR

2. Show a popup when the BleService changes rather than having a footer view.

Another option would be to create some custom renders. You can do this natively on iOS adding the [View to the RootViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850436/add-a-uiview-above-all-even-the-navigation-bar/21850877). For the other platforms, I'm not too sure, so you could go down some custom renderer road to try to get it with a footer but I don't think it is worth the headache.

Again not ideal solutions but some platforms can control this very well so I can see why Xamarin.Forms doesn't have this, built in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I opt for the first solution. I can't lose more time.

Comment: What about creating a partial view with isVisible and pass it as true in the other pages when you want to show it. Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'd like to know what do you think about.

In the App.Xaml, in the Control Template, I've binded the Command of the connection button as you can see below:

```
<buttons:SfButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
    Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.ConnectCommand}"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsNotConnected, Source={x:Static local:Pen.Current}}"/>
```

Then I've modified the class ViewModelBase, so any new View will inherit the link to Bluetooth Service and the Command Execution:

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
{
    protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }
    protected IBLEService BLEService { get; private set; }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
}

public ViewModelBase(INavigationService nS,IBLEService bS)
{
    NavigationService = nS;
    BLEService = bS;
}

public virtual void Destroy()
{
}

private DelegateCommand connectCommand;
public DelegateCommand ConnectCommand => connectCommand ?? 
    (connectCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteConnectCommand));

async void ExecuteConnectCommand()
{
    await BLEService.Connect();
}
```

What do you think about?
Thanks a lot and have a nice day,
Andrea