# Add multiple UIWindow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow

I am adding a new UIWIndow over another to display a view, but it is not showing anything and the screen just gets a little blurred. Here is the code:

```
UIWindow* topWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[topWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelNormal];

CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight,   viewController.view.frame.size.width, statusBarHeight - 1)];
[overlay setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[viewController.view addSubview:overlay];
[topWindow setRootViewController:viewController];

[topWindow setHidden:NO];
[topWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[topWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

viewController = nil;

overlay = nil;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you add this line `viewController = nil;`?

Comment: Removing the last two lines also don't have any impact

Comment: Check out here.It should bring you closer to doing things like tha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189078/multiple-views-in-a-uiwindow

Comment: Did you increase the window level ? window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1

Answer (score 4):

I wanna do like you too.

```
@implementation TAAppDelegate {
    UIWindow *win;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        win = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        win.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
        win.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        win.rootViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;
        [win makeKeyAndVisible];
    });
    return YES;
}
.....
```

And I did it. I think you should **retain your new UIWindows**. (I'm using ARC so I defined 1 local var to retain it)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Set windowLevel property to another value.
I usually use:

```
topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
```

Comment: This is the way used by many libraries. You can see in many Toast library. Also you don't need to call makeKeyAndVisible, just create it. And why you set [topWindow setHidden:NO]; ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to create a second window to overlay the main one?

From the Apple docs:

"A UIWindow object coordinates the presentation of one or more views on a screen. Most apps have only one window, which presents content on the main screen, but apps may have an additional window for content displayed on an external display."

You should be presenting your additional viewController modally or using "UIViewController containment". All within the one window.

Comment: Actually i am making Custom View Just Like UIAlertView for iOS7 + iOS6 support and need to display it over all other views. I have tried adding on my single view but it display on wrong orientation because i am displaying over rootviewcontroller. Soo my next solution was to add a new window and give my custom view as rootview so that it can get rotation events.

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary If you do it properly and display your view using a viewController, then it can handle rotation.

Comment: I can't add a new ViewController as a root and only root can have rotation events. In that case is creating a new UIWindow not the right solution????

Comment: No, if you add view controllers properly as child view controllers, they receive rotation events from the root view controller. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1